# Stripe payment in laravel

Tags: laravel, curl, stripe-payments

I have been trying to integrate stripe payment in laravel.

But  when i try to create a customer in stripe,it won't created.

Here is my code,

```
try
{

     $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
                              'email' => $this->user_email,
                              'card'  => $this->stripe_token
                              )); 

     echo "<pre>";
print_r($customer);exit;
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
                             'customer' => $customer->id,
                             'amount'   => $amountstripe,
                             'currency' => 'EUR'
                             ));

}
```

I got an error message like,

Could not connect to Stripe (https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers). Please check your internet connection and try again. If this problem persists, you should check Stripe's service status at https://twitter.com/stripestatus, or let us know at support@stripe.com.

(Network error [errno 6]: Could not resolve host: api.stripe.com)

How can i resolve this problem?

Comment: "Could not resolve host: api.stripe.com" that means you internet can not get connection with `api.stripe.com`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error with Laravel or Stripe, but "simply" a network error. Your server cannot send requests to Stripe's API because it cannot resolve the hostname `api.stripe.com` to an IP address.

You'd need to get in touch with your network administrator or hosting provider and ask them to check the connectivity between your server and Stripe's. The following script may be helpful in diagnosing the issue: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-reachability#stripe-reachability